# Bookmarking a question/answer

Tags: support

Is there a mechanism to save or bookmark a particular post for future reference? Something similar to a reddit "Save" and not bookmarking using one's browser.

Answer (score 4):

The closest mechanic we have to bookmarking is to "favorite" the question. This is done by clicking the star next to the voting. At any time, you can look at your favorites by going to your profile and clicking the "favorites" tab.

Is that close enough to what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks!